# displaying the input box for a different model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I have following two model classes:

```
 public partial class EmployeeInfo
{
    public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;

    public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<EmergencyInfo> EmergencyInfos { get; } = new List<EmergencyInfo>();
}

public partial class EmergencyInfo
{
     public string emailAddress { get; set; } = null!;

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual EmployeeInfo EmployeeInfo { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

My Razor view to create a new employee looks like this:

```
@model AckPackage.Models.EmployeeInfo
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

  <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control input-lg" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control input-lg" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
  </div>
```

Can I display the input box for emeregencyInfo, emailAddress and phone number in above view. I want to show both the input box for emailAddress and PhoneNumber in the same EmployeeInfo view so that users can input their information.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a compound class and pass it to the view as data model:

```cs
public class Info
{
    public EmployeeInfo? Employee { get; set; }
    public EmergencyInfo? Emergency { get; set; }
}
```

The view code:

```
@model Info;
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}
<form method="post" asp-action="Create">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label asp-for="@Model.Employee.LastName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.Employee.LastName" class="form-control input-lg" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Employee.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    ...
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form
```

On the controller side:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Info data)
{
    // Processing the entered data 
    ....

    return View(data);
}
```